# Automatically send email with php data on opening

Tags: php, email

I want to Automatically send mydelf an email containing the generated php data on opening of the webpage. is this possible?

```
$string ='"'.$QUERY_STRING.'","' // everything after "?" in the URL
  .$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'","' // ip address
  .$hostname.'","' // hostname
  .$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].'","' // browser and operating system
  .$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'","' // where they got the link for this page
  .$details->loc.'","' // latitude, longitude
  .$details->org.'","' // internet service provider
  .$details->city.'","'  // city
  .$details->region.'","' // state
  .$details->country.'","' // country
  .date("D dS M,Y h:i a").'"' // date
  ."\n"
  ;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the php Mail function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

But you would probably be better off with PHPMailer

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: This doesn't actually answer their question. Additionally, please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions. [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.